# Why can't we pass a {} block with other parameters to a method in Ruby

Tags: ruby

When passing a block to a method in ruby with other parameters, why do we have to do it like that

```
def method4(condition, attribute, &block)
    return "No Block" if block.nil?
    if condition
        block.call
    end
    puts attribute
end


method4(true,4) do
  puts "Hello World"
end
```

While we can't do it like that

```
method4(true,4,{puts "Hello World"})
```

Apparently the latter is syntactically wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only pass other objects as arguments, and blocks are not objects in Ruby. Blocks are syntactic constructs.

But they can easily be wrapped in objects, objects of [`Proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Proc.html) class. There is even a special shorthand operator for that:

```
method4(true, 4, &->{puts 'Hello World'})
```

A short explanation of above code:

`->{}` creates a `Proc` object around given block. As `method4` requires a block, and not an object, you need to "unwrap" it to block once more, and that's why ampersand is there. If the signature of `method4` were instead:

```
def method4(condition, attribute, proc) # note no ampersand
```

you would be able to omit the ampersand in method call too.

Comment: a few notes to add. Firstly all things in Ruby are objects. Right now `{puts "Hello World"}` is actually just misuse of the `Hash` short hand. Secondly ->{} is `lambda` short hand. `lambda` and a true `Proc` (e.g. `Proc.new`) are a bit different when it comes to argument checking. Also as @Ismael pointed out this could be called as `method4 (true, 4) { puts 'Hello World'}`

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax to call a method with block is `method_name(arguments) { stuff() }`

In `method4(true,4,{puts "Hello World"})` the curly braces gives you a syntax error, since, it could be a Hash object, like: `method4(true, 4, {puts: "Hello World"})`